# JSON.parse: unexpected character with simple php

Tags: ajax, json

Can anyone tell me why this piece of javascript code

```
result=JSON.parse(result);
alert("errori :"+result);
```

gives me an error when te php page that return JSON is this

```
<?php
$var="a";
$var2="b";
echo json_encode(array("1"=>$var,"2"=>$var2));
die;
?>
```

?
The error is : "JSON.parse: unexpected character."

Comment: Show us the generated json.

Comment: Maybe its already parsed and you're trying to parse it again?